# Autofac fails to resolve types from certain assemblies at runtime, works from debugger

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, signalr, asp.net-web-api2, autofac

In my solution I have more assemblies. Some of them include an Autofac module with registrations from the assembly. I wire all the registrations together right after startup. So far everything worked fine, I created dependencies by constructor injection and Autofac helped me to resolve the dependencies.

(In this project I host SignalR and WebApi functionality in a Console application. I use OWIN as well.)

After I added WebApi and created my first controller with DI, I faced a problem. In the constructor of `MyController` I have a dependency on `MyInterface`. When I try to call any methods on my controller I got the ordinary

> None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'MyController' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
>   Cannot resolve parameter 'MyInterface myInt' of constructor 'Void .ctor(MyInterface)'.

exception. What I noticed:

- If I replace `MyInterface` with another one from another assembly the controller is loaded.
- `MyInterface` could be resolved in another place in my code (in another assembly)

I went on with some debugging. I tried to resolve some classes right at startup in my OWIN Startup class. What I see now is

- I cannot resolve any type from `MyAssembly1`, `MyAssembly2`
- I can resolve all types from `MyAssembly3`, `MyAssembly4`
- `container.Resolve<MyInterface>` **throws exception** from code
- `container.Resolve<MyInterface>` gives back the **resolved class** if I resolve it from by Watch window in Visual Studio during debug
- I see **all** registration in `container.ComponentRegistry.Registrations`

Could you please tell me, what do I wrong?

### Update

I try to provide all necessary information, please, let me know if I still forgot something.

Here is the Autofac module definition in AssemblyA

```
public class AutofacModuleConfig : Module, IAutofacModuleConfig
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<MyWorkingImplementation>().As<IMyWorkingInterface>();

        base.Load(builder);
    }
```

Here is the Autofac module definition in AssemblyB

```
public class AutofacModuleConfig : Module, IAutofacModuleConfig
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<MyNotWorkingImplementation>().As<IMyNotWorkingInterface>();

        base.Load(builder);
    }
}
```

In the assembly where the WebHost is set up there's a registration for the controllers (in the same structure as before)

```
builder.RegisterApiControllers(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

This is how I register things at application startup

```
private void RegisterModuleDependencies()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterType<Core.Logger.Log4NetLogger>().As<ILogger>();

    var moduleConfigs = GetModuleConfigurations();
    foreach (var module in moduleConfigs)
        builder.RegisterModule(module);

    container = builder.Build();
}

private List<Autofac.Module> GetModuleConfigurations()
{
    var type = typeof(IAutofacModuleConfig);
    var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
        .Where(p => type.IsAssignableFrom(p) && p.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null);
    return types.Select(t => (Autofac.Module)Activator.CreateInstance(t)).ToList();
}
```

This is the startup method for SignalR and WebApi

```
private void Startup(IAppBuilder app)
{
    IDependencyResolver resolver = new AutofacDependencyResolver(container);
    GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = resolver;

    ...

    ConfigureOAuth(app, resolver.Resolve<IAuthorizationService>());

    app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    app.MapSignalR(new HubConfiguration
    {
        Resolver = resolver,
        EnableDetailedErrors = true,
        EnableJavaScriptProxies = false
    });

    //Host WebApi
    HttpConfiguration webApiConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration();
    webApiConfiguration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    webApiConfiguration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultWebApi", "api/{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
    webApiConfiguration.Services.Add(typeof(System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling.IExceptionLogger), new WebApiExceptionLogger());
    webApiConfiguration.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
    app.UseWebApi(webApiConfiguration);
}
```

For testing purposes I included the ValuesController used in common examples. With a default constructor it works fine naturally. If I add the constructor with `IMyWorkingInterface` then, as its name implies, it works perfectly. However, if I include the constructor with `IMyNotWorkingInterface` instead of the working one then I got the exception.

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    //private readonly TestNamespaceInAssemblyB.IMyNotWorkingInterface notWorkingInstance;

    //public ValuesController(TestNamespaceInAssemblyB.IMyNotWorkingInterface notWorkingInstance)
    //{
    //  this.notWorkingInstance = notWorkingInstance;
    //}

    private readonly TestNamespaceInAssemblyA.IMyWorkingInterface workingInstance;

    public ValuesController(TestNamespaceInAssemblyA.IMyWorkingInterface workingInstance)
    {
        this.workingInstance = workingInstance;
    }
```

I would like to point it again when I add `IMyNotWorkingInterface` as a dependency in another assembly (let's say AssemblyC) then it gets resolved by Autofac without error.

And in debugger I see the registration `MyNotWorkingImplementation` in Watch window. What more, I could even resolve it from the Debugger as you can see it on the image.

[image]

### Update 2

I created event handlers for Autofac events and here's the log showing what happens when I try to inject `IMyNotWorkingInterface`

```
2017-01-08 13:32:36.920753 | [0x00002acc] | DEBUG | Core        - WebHost                                   | AGENT  | Chile lifetime scope started
2017-01-08 13:32:36.934754 | [0x00002acc] | DEBUG | Core        - WebHost                                   | AGENT  | Resolve operation started
2017-01-08 13:32:36.936754 | [0x00002acc] | DEBUG | Core        - WebHost                                   | AGENT  | Instance lookup is beginning for Activator = ValuesController (DelegateActivator), Services = [API.Agent.Web.Controllers.ValuesController], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = None, Ownership = ExternallyOwned
2017-01-08 13:32:36.938754 | [0x00002acc] | DEBUG | Core        - WebHost                                   | AGENT  | Instance lookup is beginning for Activator = ValuesController (ReflectionActivator), Services = [API.Agent.Web.Controllers.ValuesController], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = None, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope
2017-01-08 13:32:36.939754 | [0x00002acc] | DEBUG | Core        - AutofacModuleConfig                       | AGENT  | Resolve for was requested by Activator = ValuesController (ReflectionActivator), Services = [API.Agent.Web.Controllers.ValuesController], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = None, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope
2017-01-08 13:32:36.966757 | [0x00002acc] | DEBUG | Core        - WebHost                                   | AGENT  | Resolve operation finished
2017-01-08 13:32:36.967757 | [0x00002acc] | ERROR | Core        - WebHost                                   | AGENT  | 
Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'API.Agent.Web.Controllers.ValuesController' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'TestNamespaceInAssemblyB.IMyNotWorkingInterface notWorkingInstance' of constructor 'Void .ctor(TestNamespaceInAssemblyB.IMyNotWorkingInterface)'.
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Registration.ExternalRegistrySource.<>c__DisplayClass8.<RegistrationsFor>b__3(IComponentContext c, IEnumerable`1 p)
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
2017-01-08 13:32:38.085869 | [0x000029c4] | DEBUG | Core        - WebHost                                   | AGENT  | Child lifetime scope closed
```

Any idea to where could I stick some debugging code into Autofac? (By the way, I use Autofac 3.5.2)

Comment: Not enough info. You need to post the code showing how you enumerate through your assemblies and where you register things. The long and short of what you're seeing: Autofac doesn't have `MyInterface` registered.

Comment: I can't see how this could be related to your problem, or even if maybe you forgot to include it in your code, but when you use Autofac, OWIN and Web API,  you should call `app.UseAutofacMiddleware(IContainer)` and `app.UseAutofacWebApi(HttpConfiguration)` before calling `app.UseWebApi` as shown in [the documentation](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/webapi.html#owin-integration). Could you try that just in case?

Comment: @MickaëlDerriey Thanks for the tip but unfortunately it didn't help. The problem is the same

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you register your controllers. You need to include the WebApi specific nuget package for autofac and call the following method from your container builder at startup:

```
RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

Comment: Sadly, the problem is not so simple. I had this call in my code.

Comment: If you could share your sample I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I could get over the problem but I simply cannot tell why it didn't work.

So here is the structure of the output:

```
.\Modules\AssemblyB.dll
.\AssemblyA.dll
.\Autofac.dll
.\...
.\Application.exe
```

I don't have any reference for AssemblyB in any of my projects. During startup I scan the Module folder for modules and I load them by calling `Assembly.LoadFrom("...\Modules\AssemblyB.dll")` After I load all the modules I call the `RegisterModuleDependencies()` method described in the question. After this setup I get the `DependencyResolutionException`.

**Solution:**

If I simply copy AssemblyB.dll from Modules folder to the root folder and I modify the assembly loading logic to load this module from the root folder then my problem vahises and I could use the `ValuesController` with my `IMyNotWorkingInterface` as well.

*If somebody could tell me what happened here and why the original solution didn't work (and even tell me what to do in order to keep the modules in a different folder) I will accept that as an answer.*

Comment: Try loadfile instead of loadfrom.

Comment: Seems to not be loading the assembly context. Try assigning a private bin on your appdomain. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup.privatebinpath.aspx